# iPhone SDK inString Function

Tags: iphone, cocoa

Im trying to write a method that will pull out the ID from a URI String. My code below seems inefficient, what would be a better way of finding the id string?

```
NSString *aID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.example.com/id368907840?mt=8&uo=4"] autorelease];
NSArray *arrStr = [aID componentsSeparatedByString:@"/id"];
aID = [arrStr objectAtIndex:1];
arrStr = [aID componentsSeparatedByString:@"?mt="];
aID = [arrStr objectAtIndex:0];
```

The above leaves me with the NSString = 368907840

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NSURL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [-lastPathComponent](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/lastPathComponent), [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) [-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBJFBGC), and [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [+letterCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/letterCharacterSet) to accomplish the same task as in the following example:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/id368907840?mt=8&uo=4"];
NSString* lastpath = [url lastPathComponent]; // "id368907840"
NSCharacterSet* letters = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
NSString* result = [lastpath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:letters]; // 368907840
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried this, so you will need to try it yourself, but I believe this should work.

Comment: thanks i combined this with:
lastpath = [lastpath substringFromIndex:2]; // "368907840"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of subStringWithRange and rangeOfString, something along the lines of

```
NSString *aID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.example.com/id368907840?mt=8&uo=4"] autorelease];

int startIndex = [aID rangeOfString:@"id"].location + 2;
int length = [aID rangeOfString:@"mt"].location - startIndex - 1;

aID = [aID substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. One of those cases where it's easier and more readable to use them.

Comment: i did not think there was regex in cocoa?